# C++: create a service funcition library using a template class defined in another library

Tags: c++, templates

hi guys this is my first question so be gentle please XD;
so i defined a lista.h file including the list class definition:

```
#ifndef LISTA_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTA_H_INCLUDED

template <class TipoElem>
class Lista{  // realizzazione con vettore

public:
    //tipi
    typedef int posizione;
    //operatori

    Lista();
    Lista(const Lista<TipoElem>&);
    ~Lista();

    void crea();
    bool vuota() const;
    posizione primo() const;
    bool fine(posizione) const;
    TipoElem leggi(posizione) const;
    void scrivi(posizione,TipoElem);
    posizione successivo(posizione);
    posizione precedente(posizione);
    void inserisci(posizione, TipoElem);
    void rimuovi(posizione);

private:
    TipoElem elementi[64];
    posizione lunghezza;
};

template <class TipoElem>
 Lista<TipoElem>::Lista(){
    crea();
};

template <class TipoElem>
 Lista<TipoElem>::Lista(const Lista<TipoElem>& L){
    lunghezza=L.lunghezza;
    for(int i=0;i<lunghezza;i++){
        elementi[i]=L.elementi[i];
    }
};

template <class TipoElem>
 Lista<TipoElem>::~Lista(){

}

template <class TipoElem>
void Lista<TipoElem>::crea(){
    lunghezza=0;
}

template <class TipoElem>
 bool Lista<TipoElem>::vuota() const{
    return (lunghezza==0);
}

template <class TipoElem>
 typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione Lista<TipoElem>::primo() const{
    return (1);
}

template <class TipoElem>
 bool Lista<TipoElem>::fine(posizione p) const{

        return (p==lunghezza+1);

}

template <class TipoElem>
 TipoElem Lista<TipoElem>::leggi(posizione p) const{
    return elementi[p];
}

template <class TipoElem>
 void Lista<TipoElem>::scrivi(posizione p, TipoElem e){
    elementi[p]=e;
}

template <class TipoElem>
 typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione Lista<TipoElem>::successivo(posizione p){
    if(p>0 && p<lunghezza+1){
        return (p+1);
    }
    else return p;
}

template <class TipoElem>
typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione Lista<TipoElem>::precedente(posizione p){
    if(p>0 && p<lunghezza+1){
        return (p-1);
    }
    else return p;
}

template <class TipoElem>
 void Lista<TipoElem>::inserisci(posizione p, TipoElem e){
for(int q=lunghezza-1;q>p;q--){
    elementi[q+1]=elementi[q];
}
scrivi(p,e);
lunghezza++;
}

template <class TipoElem>
 void Lista<TipoElem>::rimuovi(posizione p){
    for (int q=p;q<lunghezza-1;q++){
        elementi[q]=elementi[q+1];
    }
    lunghezza--;

}


#endif // LISTA_H_INCLUDED
```

Next is the header file of the library including service functions:

```
#ifndef LISTA_OP_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTA_OP_H_INCLUDED

#include "Lista.h"

template<class TipoElem>
void stampa(Lista<TipoElem>& l);


template <class TipoElem>
void copia(typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione src, Lista<TipoElem> srcL, typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione dest, Lista<TipoElem> destL,bool finecatena);

template <class TipoElem>
void copiaCatena(typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione src, Lista<TipoElem> srcL, typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione dest, Lista<TipoElem> destL,bool finecatena);

template<class TipoElem>
void fondicatena(typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione srcA, Lista<TipoElem> srcLA,typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione srcB, Lista<TipoElem> srcLB, typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione dest, Lista<TipoElem> destL);

template<class TipoElem>
void merge(Lista<TipoElem> A,Lista<TipoElem> B,Lista<TipoElem> L,int numCatene);

template<class TipoElem>
void distribuisci(Lista<TipoElem> A,Lista<TipoElem> B,Lista<TipoElem>L);

template<class TipoElem>
void ordina(Lista<TipoElem> L);


#endif // LISTA_OP_H_INCLUDED
```

and the .cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Lista_op.h"

using namespace std;


template <class TipoElem>
 void stampa(Lista<TipoElem>& l){
typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione p=l.primo();
while(!l.fine(p)){
    while(!l.fine(p)){
    std::cout<<"n:"<<p<<"  v:"<<l.leggi(p)<<"\n";
    p=l.successivo(p);
}
}

system("PAUSE");
}


template <class TipoElem>
void copia(typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione src, Lista<TipoElem> srcL, typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione dest, Lista<TipoElem> destL,bool finecatena){
TipoElem elemento=srcL.leggi(src);
destL.inserisci(dest,elemento);
src=srcL.successivo(src);
dest=destL.successivo(dest);
if(srcL.fine(src)){
    finecatena=true;
}
else {
    finecatena=(elemento>srcL.leggi(src));
}

}

template <class TipoElem>
void copiaCatena(typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione src, Lista<TipoElem> srcL, typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione dest, Lista<TipoElem> destL,bool finecatena){
finecatena=false;
do{
    copia(src.srcL,dest,destL,finecatena);
}while(finecatena);
}

template<class TipoElem>
void fondicatena(typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione srcA, Lista<TipoElem> srcLA,typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione srcB, Lista<TipoElem> srcLB, typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione dest, Lista<TipoElem> destL){
bool finecatena=false;
do{
    if(srcLA.leggi(srcA)>srcLB.leggi(srcB)){
        copia(srcA,srcLA,dest,destL,finecatena);
        if(finecatena){
        copiaCatena(srcB,srcLB,dest,destL);
        }
            }
     else {
        copia(srcB,srcLB,dest,destL,finecatena);
                if(finecatena){
        copiaCatena(srcA,srcLA,dest,destL);
     }
}
}while(finecatena);
}

template<class TipoElem>
void merge(Lista<TipoElem> A,Lista<TipoElem> B,Lista<TipoElem> L,int numCatene){
typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione pa,pb,pl;
pa=A.primo();
pb=B.primo();
pl=L.primo();
while(!A.fine(pa)&& !B.fine(pb)){
    fondicatena(pa,A,pb,B,pl,L);
    numCatene++;
}
while(!A.fine(pa)){
    copiaCatena(pa,A,pl,L);
    numCatene++;
}
while(!B.fine(pb)){
    copiaCatena(pb,B,pl,L);
    numCatene++;
}
};

template<class TipoElem>
void distribuisci(Lista<TipoElem> A,Lista<TipoElem> B,Lista<TipoElem>L){
typename Lista<TipoElem>::posizione pa,pb,pl;
pl=L.primo();
pa=A.primo();
pb=B.primo();
do{
copiaCatena(pl,L,pa,A);
if(!L.fine(pl)){
    copiaCatena(pl,L,pb,B);
}
}while(L.fine(pl));
};

template<class TipoElem>
void ordina(Lista<TipoElem> L){
int numCatene;
do{
Lista<TipoElem> A;
Lista<TipoElem> B;
distribuisci(A,B,L);
numCatene=0;
Lista<TipoElem> L;
merge(A,B,L,numCatene);
}while(numCatene==0);
};
```

and this is is the main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "Lista_op.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){


Lista<int> A,B;


Lista<int>::posizione pa=A.primo();
int b=9;
while(pa<11){
    A.inserisci(pa,pa+b);
    b=b-2;
    pa=A.successivo(pa);
}
stampa(A); /*!!!!!*/

ordina(A); /*!!!!!*/

stampa(A); /*!!!!!*/

return 0;
}
```

here's the problem, in main returns this error  :

undefined reference to `void stampa<int>(Lista<int>&)'| undefined reference to` void ordina(Lista)'|

what i'm doing wrong?

i want to create a generic list class and a generic series of service function that will work if i change the list.h (so i can use vector or pointers based list).

thank you allfor the help and the patience in reading this looooong question :D

Comment: Templates aren't real code - the compiler only generates code when it instances a template. So, you can't have a separate .cpp file for class template definitions because the compiler won't be able to find it when it tries to generate an instance. You've got to include it all in the header.

Comment: so i have to merge Lista_op.h and Lista_op.cpp?

Comment: Right, the definitions you wrote in Lista_op.cpp need to be part of Lista_op.h

Comment: are you sure? consider that the class definition is in Lista.h

Comment: Oh, right, good catch. The definitions should be in the same file as the class declaration.